# Extending jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to extend jQuery's datepicker via the `$.widget` function, jQuery UI 1.10.3, with `$.ui.datepicker` as the base.

It seems that `$.ui.datepicker` is an object (unlike pretty much all the other widgets) and `$.widget` throws a TypeError when trying to instantiate the base.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: The datepicker does **not** use the widget factory and thus you can't use it to extend it; AFAIK it's the only jQueryUI widget that does this. You'll probably find an answer to your question [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7733904/2685386)

Comment: Seems like a [rewrite](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6228) is under way. I have a working (but hacky and ugly) solution to my specific problem, but was hoping for a way to pretty it up a bit. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: That rewrite was supposed to have already made it in several major releases, so I wouldn't hold my breath; as for prettying up stuff, the question linked above has a fairly clean (if verbose) solution in using the widget factory as a wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments by [blgt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685386/blgt):

> The datepicker does not use the widget factory and thus you can't use it to extend it

It seems like there is a [rewrite](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6228) underway, which should implement Datepicker using the widget factory.