# Uncaught TypeError: e.widget.extend is not a function in SugarCRM when two widgets are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, sugarcrm

I encountered this problem when we installed 2 widgets on our SugarCRM, by widget I mean just for example there are 2 facebook chats present in our SugarCRM (One is an actual chat the other one is for calls and they are like facebook chat because they are always on the screen whatever page you go to)

The file error is this: **jQuery v2.1.3**
Along this line:

```
this.options = e.widget.extend({}, this.options, this._getCreateOptions(), t),
```

I read that it could be caused by declaring jquery-ui twice in the same page, but when I checked the included javascript of the first widget there was no jquery-ui inside it.

How can I best trap this error and find the root cause?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no [extend](http://api.jquery.com/extend) method but there is [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com) method. You should use like this:

```
$.extend({}, object1, object2, objectN);
```

But I think you need to use $.widget method. See the following to get help with widget factory method:

https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/

[How to extend an existing jQuery UI widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711127/how-to-extend-an-existing-jquery-ui-widget)

Comment: is it alright if I changed that since it is the minified version of the jquery file?