# Overriding the JQuery $ui.progressbar to change its width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

After a few hours, I was able to override the function responsible for changing the element width that corresponds to the [progress bar widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar), managed by **jQuery UI** *v1.12.1 - 2016-09-14*.

First I wanted the progress bar (completed) to fill completely within the column of a table. However, by default, the `"ui.progressbar"` widget writes `"100%"` in the width of the element. However, I needed the width to be `"calc(100% + 30px)"`.

Below the problem, and then I will give the answer to my problem. I hope it will be useful to someone, as it was for me.

**Default cenary**: JQuery UI set 102% to the width of the first div

```
<td class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-progressbar-indeterminate" id="divProgress-255" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0">
   <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header" style="width: 102%;">
         <div class="ui-progressbar-overlay"></div>
   </div>
 </td>
```

**jquery-ui.js (line 133467)**: Line of JQuery UI responsible for this writing

```
this.valueDiv.toggle( this.indeterminate || value > this.min ).width( percentage.toFixed( 0 ) + "%" );
```

**The progress bar image is as below**

[image]

**Question**: How to make the `$ui.progressbar` widget set the width of this element with `"calc(percentage + increment)"` and no more `"100%"`?

Answer (score 2):

**My solution**

1) I created a `_calc` function and overrided the `_refreshValue` function as bellow:

```
$.widget("ui.progressbar", $.ui.progressbar, {
    _calc: function(percentage) {
        percentage = percentage.toFixed(0);
        return this.options.calc ? ("calc("+percentage+"% + "+this.options.calc_inc+"px)") : percentage+"%";
    },
    _refreshValue: function() {
        this._super();
        this.valueDiv.width( this._calc(this._percentage()) );
    }
});
```

2) I configured my progress bar in a column:

```
function progressBarSettings() {
    $('td[id^=divProgress]').progressbar("option", {
       calc: true,
       calc_inc: 30
    });
}
```

3) The progress bar image is as below:

[image]

4) My references:
[Extending widgets 1](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets) or
[Extending widgets 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711127/how-to-extend-an-existing-jquery-ui-widget)